# ScaleLine of OL5 doesn't work with EPSG:25832

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I try to migrate my Map-Viewer from OL 4.6.5 to the newest 5.0.0 and i get a trouble with the ScaleLine.

Here is an example code and as you can see the ScaleLine shows wrong values and also change the length on panning map.

[example code](https://jsfiddle.net/76e8vzrh/2/)

```js
proj4.defs("EPSG:25832", "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");

var extent = [365000, 5654000, 450000, 5733500];
var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
 extent: extent,
 source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
  url: 'http://geoportal.iserlohn.de/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/intranet/html/map/kaskade_stadtplan_grau.map&',
  params: {
   'LAYERS': 'stadtplan,sie02_f,gew01_f,ver03_f,veg02_f,veg01_f,veg03_f,ver04_f,ver01_f,gew01_l,ver03_l_u,ver02_l,ver01_l_2_1,ver01_l,ver01_l_2,ver03_l_o,ver02_l_2,ver01_l_d,ver02_l_d,ver01_l_d2,ver01_l_d3,ver01_l_d3_2,ver01_bab_ausfahrten,sie01_f_a,ax_gebaeude_pg_shadow1,ax_gebaeude_pg_shadow2,ax_gebaeude_pg,ax_gebaeude_pg_uebersicht,beschr_hnr,stadtgeb,stadtgrenze', 
   'FORMAT' : 'image/jpeg', 
   transparent: false},
  ratio: 1.1,
  serverType: 'mapserver'
 })
});
 

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer],
  target: 'map',
  logo:false,
  view: new ol.View({
 projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:25832',
        extent: extent,
        units: 'm'
      }),
    center: [406523.08, 5693898.11],
    minZoom: 1,
 maxZoom: 10,
 zoom: 3
  })
});

map.addControl(new ol.control.ScaleLine());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.0.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.0.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4-src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%;padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
```

The same example works with v4.6.5 without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When moving to Openlayers 5, you cannot use the global variable for proj4 without registering it with openlayers first.

This is done by calling `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4)`

Please see the notes on the changes for version 5 here: [Release v5.0.0](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

Comment: Thank you! It is exact the solution.

I read the release notes and tried it:
register(proj4);

but of course, it was wrong becouse of the new modular syntax.
In the "normal" JS i've to set:
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);